# Does Word class SVG images as text and therefore limit to file size of 32mb?

Tags: microsoft-word, crash, svg

I have been happily producing Technical drawings and dropping them into a Word document. All was going well until i reached around 23mb (properties) file size. Now the file crashes every time i try to add more images.

I've tried removing from table and also am now using a new set of images - but same thing happening. It either crashes or wants to Save As (but will not allow to save as!)

Also tried striping the document back to bare minimum!

As far as i am aware Word 2016 has a text limit of 32mb but total file limit of including images of 500mb?!

The Tech Drawing images are SVG and around 60 to 100kb (not massive), is word counting the SVG files as text?

Your help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I believe the issue is SVG files as base text using up 32mb limit, exchanged for PNG now saves no problem.

Comment: Instead of using PNG, to not loose the favours of SVG (to keep the vector graphic scalable) you might consider to export your SVG in EPS, EMF or PDF format. It should be better supported than SVG, since that is relatively new to Word.